# Is there a way to hide a button but make it clickable?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm making a software with `wxpython`, and I creating a logo with a website that helps make logos, and I want to create an invisible button behind that logo that when the logo is clicked I will perform something, So is there a way to make the button invisible but clickable ?

[This image](https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2020-02-14/12/untitled-designh-1-5e46736dc0040.png)

And I want to create on the **Exit** text an invisible button that when the exit is clicked, it will quit the software, is there a way ?

Comment: `wx.BitmapButton` ?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony But I don't want to make a bitmap button because It will make the whole image as a button, I want to paste an image to my software and then make an invisible button under the image.

Comment: Where, under the image will it hide? Top left, bottom right? If it's invisible, how will the user know it's there, let alone the correct part of the image to click! Perhaps, you need to give your idea some more thought or explain the issue better, so that someone has a chance of providing an answer/suggestion, more to your liking.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Have you read my question ? Look at my Image I want the button to be under the **Exit** text.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me. I read that as a separate request, note the word "And"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one simple way to achieve what you are after by binding mouse events to the image.
Ensure that the image is essentially fixed in size or you will have to start calculating positions.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Mouse Control')
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel3 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.aBitmap = wx.Image(name = "image_button.png").ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bm = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel2, -1, self.aBitmap)
        self.bm.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick)
        self.bm.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.onAccess)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.panel1,0)
        vbox.Add(self.panel2,0)
        vbox.Add(self.panel3,0)
        self.panel1.SetMinSize(self.bm.GetSize())
        self.panel2.SetMinSize(self.bm.GetSize())
        self.panel3.SetMinSize(self.bm.GetSize())
        self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        self.panel3.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        self.SetSizerAndFit(vbox)
        self.Show()

    def onClick(self, event):
        x,y = event.GetPosition()
        if y > 25 and y < 50:
            if x > 30 and x < 170:
                wx.MessageBox("Contact", "Contact Header")
            elif x > 800 and x < 860:
                wx.MessageBox("Exit", "Exit Header")
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def onAccess(self, event):
        x,y = event.GetPosition()
        if y > 25 and y < 50:
            if x > 30 and x < 170:
                self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND))
            elif x > 800 and x < 860:
                self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND))
            else:
                self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_DEFAULT))
        else:
            self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_DEFAULT))
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This code indicates that you are over a `hotspot` (Contact us, Exit) by changing the cursor.

[image][image]